# PowerPoint footer/header logos: best practices

Tags: logo, microsoft-powerpoint

In the previous company I worked for, they'd **always** add their logo in all of a PowerPoint's pages. Cover, content page, chapter pages, everywhere. In my current one, they're fine as long as their and their clients' logos are on the first page. Is there a best pracice for this? For instance:

- Do you place your logos in all of the pages, or do you just put them
  on the cover and make the corporate identity visible through the rest
  of the design?
- Should they be included in all of the pages the same way?
- Are there variables to account for when it comes to position?

Edit: I'm working with a business consulting company. The presentations are on research the company does, and then presents or hands to the clients.

Comment: I think this might get closed as too broad because of the "should we add logos" of your title. As Scott answered, we can't answer this for you since we don't really know what your project is. But I think you could edit your question and reframe it to best practices (i.e. like you say, is there a right approach to this?) For example, are there variables to account for when it comes to position? Should it be included on all pages the same way? I think that would be answerable and useful for other people too.

Answer (score 3):

> Do you place your logos in all of the pages, or do you just put them on the cover and make the corporate identity visible through the rest of the design?

I think this is more a matter of *opinion* or *design style* overall. There *aren't* any real "rules" to follow. At best, there may be some commonalities viewers expect to see, similar to page numbers always in a bottom corner - they don't *have* to be located there, but they often are.

For me, branding on slide 1 is common, but *how* branding is displayed is not always universal. I have created many PPT decks where slide 1 merely shows any branding iconography, but not the full mark (no type). If this is feasible based upon the mark. One way or another, *some* aspect of the brand is shown on slide 1. How much is more reliant on the content of the deck.... if the cover is meant to be more "teaser" than "sales" or "information", I may minimize branding in an effort to entice.

In terms of the rest of the slide deck, **yes** I place branding on every single slide (actually on the master[s]) in every PPT deck I've ever created. In my work there's been very little reason to *not* follow this procedure.

In digital delivery files, pieces can be pulled from any deck (or PDF) and saved on their own. It's important to brand everything so in these instances a stand-alone slide still references *where* it came from. There's no harm in ensuring the brand is shown on every slide/page.

> Should they be included in all of the pages the same way?

Consistency is favorable. Remaining consistent in placement and size with any branding helps convey a sense of stability and familiarity between slides as well as reducing any distraction and necessary visual reinterpretation between slides.

If a mark moves with every slide, the reader has to see it, then register it's just the same mark. If the mark is in the same position every slide, the reader registers it, then doesn't need to consciously re-register it for every slide. In essence, the reader gets "banner blindness" and branding doesn't become a prominent visual for much of the deck (although it's still there).

> Are there variables to account for when it comes to position?

This largely depends upon the mark, the overall slide layout, and any other necessary header/footer content.

My *opinion* is the best place for a mark on a slide is **upper left corner** or **lower right corner.** But that's *not* "set in stone", so to speak.

Upper left, because it's expected, very similar to the expectation of placement on web pages. People are merely used to it being there. Lower right corner can be favorable because it's the last visual anyone will register before moving to the next slide or closing the deck entirely.

There are times were upper/lower center work better, or upper right corner. The only real constant I follow is that I, personally, will **never** place a brand mark in the lower left corner. It's also exceptionally *rare* (if ever) for me to place a mark at left/right center of a slide. For me, centering vertically on slides always "feels" out of balance. But that's my aesthetic, it may not be yours.

Again, placement is really more about the slide layouts as well as the mark itself. There aren't really any universal "rules" - other than for English readers, lower left corner is generally the *least* visible area in *any* layout.